How to Run onEdit/onChange function in Google Apps Script on Data pulled Dynamically using Query
So, I am pulling some data from a Google Sheet let's say A into sheet B.
In the Sheet B, I am fetching the data from Sheet A using Query() formula.
What I need is when a new row is added to Sheet B (pulled when a new row is added to sheet A) then run a script.
What the script will do is choose a random value from the H column which is dropdown type.
The script which works by the way on non dynamic data is:
function onEdit(e){

    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow();
    const agentColumnName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8);
    const dropdownValues = agentColumnName.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0];
    agentColumnName.setValue(dropdownValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * dropdownValues.length)]);
        
}

But I want to run this on the Dynamic Data that is when a new row is added by the Query function. I read that onEdit and onChange only runs on user entered data ... but is there any workaround for that?
Please help me fix the script to work on dynamic data.... thanks
Screenshot to understand:

Query+Importrange formula in A2 of sheet B:
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXX/edit","Sheet1!A2:G"),"select *",0)


Unfortunately, in the current stage, the change of "QUERY" cannot be directly detected by OnEdit and OnChange trigger. So, in this case, it is required to check the change in the range where is used at "QUERY". But, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot know your "QUERY", the situation of your Spreadsheet, and the method for changing the cells of the range in "QUERY". So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide more information?

By the way, the logic of this situation can be also seen in this report.

@Tanaike thanks .. I have added more info in the question

Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I noticed that your "QUERY" retrieves values using "IMPORTRANGE". Unfortunately, from "Screenshot to understand:", I cannot understand your actual situation. What are your 2 images of Spreadsheets, respectively? So, I cannot still propose a clear answer. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. But, my report will be useful for your situation.

Is this sample output similar to what you're looking for?

@Saddles Yes it is exactly what I want

Try:
Try this script with an onChange() trigger.
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rg = ss.getRange(2, 8, ss.getLastRow() - 1);
  var vl = rg.getValues();
  var dv = rg.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0];
  vl.forEach((r, i) => {
    var c = rg.getCell(i + 1, 1);
    c.isBlank() ? c.setValue(dv[Math.floor(Math.random() * dv.length)]) : null;
  });
}

Result:


Hi can you tell me what should I do to make it on all sheets. Right now, it works on the first sheet (Sheet1) of the spreadsheet only.

Instead of using a trigger listening for events on the spreadsheet having the QUERY + IMPORTRANGE formula, set the trigger to listen for changes on the source spreadsheet.
Another option is to store the "sheet state" and use a time-driven trigger to compare the actual state with the previous state.
As there isn't a built-in "sheet state" you should define it. If your sheet only holds the formula, one simple way is to use the last row number. In most cases it might be required to use something more complex according to each use case.
